# SQL Find Duplicate Records Based on Two Keys Swapped Between Columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Okay, I've been trying to figure out this issue and it pains me to feel like the solution is quite simple but I just can't find the answer through google or, yet, through this site.

So...
I have a table that relates 2 project records together, by logging their respective primary keys; this table has its own identity column to maintain seperate keys for each of these records.

For example:

```
PKEY   RelKey1  RelKey2
1       ABC      ABD
2       ABC      CBH
3       CBH      DFT
4       ABD      ABC
```

Now, my issue is records 1 and 4. These records are essentially duplicates, and while it is quite easy to prevent the user from inputting duplicates through data entry; this validation was not performed on the existing project from which I am migrating data from. Unfortunately, I came across this issue after having imported the data, though, its not a big deal as its for a test environment and the suspect data is easily identifiable and can be removed as a whole; the 'relkey' refers to keys in another table, so I can delete all of these records based on other parameters and try the migration again.

I am looking at a way to:

- Delete one of the two "duplicate" records
- Or, I can remove all of the newly added data and run an insert that will only insert one of the two "duplicate" records

For the life of me, I am unable to figure this one out; everything that I've tried I've deleted as I could just look at it and know it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete the records with the following logic:  only delete records `relkey1 > relkey2` and a corresponding record `relkey1 < relkey2` exists.

In standard SQL, you would write this as:

```
delete from atable t
   where t.relkey1 > t.relkey2 and
         exists (select 1 from atable t2 where t2.relkey2 = t.relkey1 and t2.relkey1 = t.relkey2);
```

MySQL doesn't support this syntax, so you do something like:

```
delete t
    from atable t join
         (select least(relkey1, relkey2) as key1, greatest(relkey1, relkey2) as key2
          from atable t2
          group by least(relkey1, relkey2) as key1, greatest(relkey1, relkey2)
          having count(*) > 1
         ) tdup
         on t.relkey1 = tdup.relkey2 and t.relkey2 = tdup.relkey1;
```

Comment: This did work. I was missing the correct use of exists, I was trying to use an IN for both relkey1 and relkey2, and I would either return all rows or no rows. Thank you sir.